# Why is my if condition comparing strings failing? 

Tags: java, string, if-statement

This program execution is not getting inside the if condition.
 
please check the comment i have specified.

```
public static void filterObject(ArrayList<treewalker.VariableNode> variableNodeslist,
            ArrayList<treewalker.ObjectNode> objectNodeslist,
            ArrayList<treewalker.ClassNode> classNodeslist) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < variableNodeslist.size(); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < classNodeslist.size(); j++) {
                String argu1 = variableNodeslist.get(i).typeClass.toString();
                String argu2 = classNodeslist.get(j).name.toString();
                System.out.println(argu1);
                System.out.println(argu2);
                if (argu1 == argu2)//this if loop is not getting executed 
                {
                    System.out.println("inside for");
                }
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
`argu1.equals(argu2)` instead of `argu1 == argu2`

**Longer answer:** 
The `==` operator in Java does a reference compare.

You want to do string comparison, use:

```
if (argu1.equals(argu2))
```

In some case the `==` operator might seem to do a equality check for example:

```
String var1 = "abc";
String var2 = "abc";

String result = ("abc" == "abc");
```

In this  case the result is `true` which at first look seems to be an equality comparison but is fact a compiler optimisation where both `var1` and `var2` shares the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals`

```
argu1.equals(argu2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be doing  if(argu1.equals(argu2)) for string comparision. 
== will compare the hashcode. For Strings, even thought the 2 strings contain the same text, their hashcodes may differ. Hence you need to use equals() to compare the string text

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.equals()` to compare your strings, not `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if(argu1.equals(argu2))` not  `if(argu1==argu2)`

You should never use `==` to compare strings.